# Change the date format in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

I have this small query

```
SELECT 
    MAX(myDate) AS DateToUser
FROM 
    blaTable
```

I'm getting this result "2011-05-23 15:18:01.223"

how can I get the result like 05/23/2011 "mm/dd/yyyy" format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    convert(varchar, MAX(myDate), 101) AS DateToUser
FROM 
    blaTable
```

For more Date Format Parameters: [**Click Here**](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15422)**

```
SELECT 
   convert(varchar,MAX(myDate),101) AS DateToUser
FROM blaTable
```

**[CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**

If you are using SQL SERVER 2012 then Simple use **FORMAT**

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(MAX(myDate),'MM/dd/yyyy') AS DateToUser
FROM blaTable
```

**[FORMAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),MAX(myDate),101) AS DateToUser
FROM 
    blaTable
```

For more information on Sql server datetime formats have a look here

### [`SQL SERVER FORMATS`](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)